# Memory leak in the following C code

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind

How would i free the memory that is leaking fromt he following code.

```
struct object_one{
  int value;
}*object,object_node;

struct node_one {
  void **pointers;

}*node, node_node;

  node sample(){
  object number;
  node node123;
  node123 = malloc(sizeof(node_node));
  number = malloc(sizeof(object_node));
  number->valu = malloc(sizeof(int));
  number->value = 9;
  node123->pointers[0]=number; 
  free(number);
  return node123; 
}
```

Am I doing the correct way to deallocate the memory referenced by `number`.Once i do the above one, i get the error;

```
Invalid read of size 4
==15957==    at 0x403804: main (abc.c:1255)
==15957==  Address 0x540cb50 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 4 free'd
```

Please suggest me how can I prevent the memory leak in this condition? Thanks in advance.

[EDIT]

Hi actually the above mentioned is not the real code I have. But I have tried my best to refelect the sturcutre and semantics of my code. Actually I am implementing a data strcture. `number` is some temproary storage and `node123` is my real data-base. I would like to  assign the value of `number` in the database and dereference it.`number` type is a component of database.

[EDIT2]

The code corresponding to line `1255` is printing for the value that is holded by the `object i'e value`.It looks like:

```
   object tempObject;
   tempObject = search_object(root,50);
   [1255] printf("Key is %d ------>value is %d\n",50,tempObject->value);
```

Here the function`search_object` searches the value corresponding to the key `50`. The function is returning the proper value associated with the key and still it is showing such error.

Comment: Note that hiding pointers behind typedefs is considered bad practice.

Comment: It's not going to be possible to solve this unless you explain your current code some more.  Why do you have a **double** pointer in your `node_one` structure?

Comment: **node_one** is a node of tree. It holds a number of keys and the pointers of the children  node. More precisely it is a B+ tree. This is the reason why I am keeping array of pointers in my node.

Answer (score 5):

You also need to `free(node123)`.

**But this is not what the error message is telling you.**

You are also dereferencing a pointer that doesn't point at valid memory (on the line `node123->pointers[0] = number)`.  You have not allocated any memory for `pointers` to point at, so dereferencing it like this will write to a random area in memory.

Comment: my mistake, actually i want to return the **node123**. This is not the exact code i am having but it gives the exact semantics and structure of my code.I have edited my code.

Comment: @thetna: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do.  You're allocating memory for `number`, then copying that pointer, and then immediately freeing that memory.  That won't do anything useful.  Please edit your question to explain what the **aim** is here.

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion. I tried with the one you mentioned. Still I am getting the same. Could you please let me know what esle mistake I can made ?

Comment: @thetna: Well, which is line 1255?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to free(node123), it seems.

For each malloc() call you must have a free() call.

The valgrind error you show is not a memory leak, it's an invalid read in a memory region that has been free'd.

It happens in abc.c at line 1255.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a free(node123);

And also this line: node123->pointers[0]=number; is a trouble.

You didn't initialized pointers inside node123.

Comment: And also how function search_object() looks like?